# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when trying to encode a subclass of a Codable-conformant class

Tags: ios, json, swift, crash, codable

I must be a moron or something but I'm scratching my head for a third day in a row and can't figure out what's going wrong with my intention to encode some JSON data in my Swift program...

Here's the situation:
I've got two classes as follows:

```
class Node: Codable {
    // Nothing in here
}
```

and

```
class Shape: Node {
    // No code here too
}
```

Then, I have an attempt to encode the subclass as follows:

```
do {
    let encodedData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Shape())
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This is all I have added to an empty Single View App project. When I run it, I get "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x350)" crash.

[image: Actual screenshot]

Of course, initially my classes used to have a lot of properties which were Codable too. I thought it was any of them, so I stripped them off but it appears it's not the properties that are causing the crash...

I'm running Xcode 9.3 on a High Sierra MacBook Pro. Is there anyone willing to reproduce this or anyone already bumped his head into such an odd behavior?

Comment: This sounds promising. So, there must be something wrong with my setup then. Any ideas of what to reset or reinstall? Mind you, I've created a completely new project, so this should rule out any legacy from previous changes to the project itself. Perhaps it's something related to some kind of misaligned setting?

Comment: That's exactly what I did, Matt :(

Comment: With pleasure: https://github.com/stoyanmar/CodableTest

Comment: Yes, Clean Build, then closed Xcode, deleted the DerivedData for this particular project, deleted a ModuleCache subfolder of DerivedData (not sure if I had to), then restarted Xcode. Same result. Is there any other step I could undertake?

Comment: Matt, even though I'm not using simulators at all, I followed your advise and deleted all simulators, quit Xcode, emptied DerivedData folder completely, including ModuleCache, restarted the Mac and here we go again - crashing gracefully... Perhaps reinstalling Xcode is the next in line?

Comment: Yes, after your suggestion to delete the simulators I figured you must be testing it on a simulator, so I reinstalled an iPhone X simulator with no luck too. I'm usually testing on an iPad Pro - much faster and proper handling of touches.

Comment: Now you're talking! :) What did you change in order to get there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug and you can work around it by turning on Whole Module Compilation mode for the Debug configuration, or by upgrading to Xcode 10 beta.

Comment: See https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7743. I've added your github project to the report so please don't take it down.

Comment: Matt, indeed, when I changed the Compilation Mode (Debug) from Single File to Whole Module, everything is now back to normal. I hope this is the settings you mentioned. You saved my day, ugh, night! I'm very grateful for finding the source of the issue! Sure, I won't take it down any time soon.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant Compilation, I had Optimization on the brain while I was typing.